# Criação de menu usando Web2Py?

Tags: python, menu, web2py

Estou com dificuldade em criar menu no meu site usando o template padrão do Web2py, alguma dica e exemplo?

Tentei seguir exemplo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071468/adding-a-view-as-menu-item-using-menu-py-in-web2py

Só não aparece na página principal.

Comment: Você pode dar mais detalhes, colocar o que você já fez?

Comment: no arquivo models/menu.py na adicionei linha  responde.menu +=[ (T('Home'),False,URL('default','index')),  
(T('About'),False,URL('default','what')) ] , é isso que eu fiz.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta para colocar essa informação, tente colocar algo mais. procure dar um pouco mais de contexto. É difícil ajudar sem ver exatamente como está feito.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mais já conseguir resolver, estava colocando o menus no lugar errado, esta colocando dentro da definição do links para cada menu.

Comment: Coloque a sua solução como resposta então. Você pode até aceitá-la como a correta. Assim outras pessoas aprendem e você pode ganhar reputação.

Comment: Solução:  Para criar menu usando o template padrão  do            web2py basta coloca na linha                                                                                                                                                                                                        reponse.menu = [ (T('Home'),False,URL('default','index')),  
(T('About'),False,URL('default','what')),  
(T('Download'),False,URL('default','download'))                   ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para criar menu usando o template padrão do `web2py` basta coloca na linha:

```
reponse.menu = [(T('Home'), False, URL('default','index')), (T('About'),False,URL('default','what')), (T('Download'),False,URL('default','download'))]
```